# Java applets not working in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, security, java, java-applet

I really want to view the Java applet in [this website](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/applet/dfplotter/dfplotter.html). I've tried in firefox and IE and neither work. I followed [Sun's instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/win8_faq.xml) but they're inacurate: first of all there's no Java Control Pannel, however there is a configure Java. I tried lowering the security level but there's no option to go any lower 
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You say there isn't a Java control panel yet you post a picture of the Java control panel this corporate or personal computer what version of Java exactly?

Comment: It's not a problem from a "corporate"  computer since I have the same problem but it could be connected to the JDK

Comment: I'm using my personal computer. It has Java SE 8 Update 20. There is no "Java control panel", but the screen shot I posted was under "Java Preferences" (in the start menu).

Comment: Start / Control Panel / Java is the "Java control panel" You just ran the same program from a start menu shortcut.

Comment: @Fabiusp98 I also have the JDK installed